# Is there any JQuery turn effect in z-direction?

Tags: jquery

I want to ask that, is it possible to make any cover opening effect with JQuery or with any other JS code? I don't mean that page turning, I mean cover opening (like thick covers).

Comment: Can you explain the difference between a 'cover opening' and a 'page turning'?

Comment: I think the latter is done with curly-corner image that slides across and reveals next page and former is the actual transformation (scaling, panning) of the page image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is not possible in current browsers, at least not in any proper way. In the future, you'll be able to use CSS 3D Transforms to do that kind of stuff but that's a long way ahead. [Read more about CSS 3D Transorms here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/).

The reason why a good lookin cover opening effect is impossible is that the 'cover' should be skewed and stretched for it to look good, and that's just not possible, even with Javascript.

The only effect you'll be able to do with basic CSS + JS is a page whose width is animated so that it looks kinda like a page turn, but it's not very convincing.

If you're willing to work with canvases, that might have some possibilities. Haven't seen it done anywhere yet though – I guess 3D stuff on canvas can be a bit tricky.

Comment: Thans for information, actually i only thought that, if we can rotate images into x and y direction, we could in z-direction as well. But you all right it makes that sublect is 3D. Anyway, let me wait for CSS 3D Transform :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of (besides using canvas) would require the "cover" to be an image and you could basically squash the image vertically over a short period of time, while keeping it anchored to the top of the container.

It's certainly not perfect, but it could simulate the look maybe pretty closely.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do it directly on client with JS only. Here's one way it can be done:

1. Take snapshot of the page by transforming it to the image (something like on http://webthumb.bluga.net/home). This step most likely needs to be done on server
2. AJAX image back into a canvas
3. Use animation to scale the image